# spring boot rest versioned request and select controller dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We are planning to apply versioning to our REST API. We do not want to change the URL so the idea that we are going with is to have a X-API-VERSION in the HTTP header. When this header value is present the request is forwarded to correct versioned rest controller.

e.g. we have two controller for the same resource i.e. Person resource

PersonController
Person_Version_1_5_Controller

If X-API-VERSION is NOT present in the HTTP Header then spring by default will call the PersonController.

If X-API-VERSION is PRESENT in the HTTP Header then it should call Person_Version_1_5_Controller.

So how can we achieve this switching between controllers using spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers--), it looks like the `header` parameter of `RequestMapping` might be useful in such cases:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", headers = "X-API-VERSION=...")
```

Comment: Sanjay, thanks for the reply. This looks promising and will try it out thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle.

Instead of keeping controllers for different versions in the same application deployment (Person_Version_1_5_Controller is not a pretty name, by the way), you could split them in separate JARs / application deployments, e.g. **app-v1.jar** and **app-v2.jar**. You could do the routing on a higher level in your stack, using a HTTP-header based load-balancer that would forward the request to the correct version of the app depending on the version header specified in the request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So right now we are planing this as a POC and just wanted to know if its possible to do this "switching" using Spring. So any code example would be helpful. Thanks again.